# eee pc+ubuntu 9.04+three mobile broadband - why do some sites not load in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: ubuntu, browser, eee-pc

When I'm using my [three mobile](http://three.co.uk/) broadband dongle, I've noticed that some sites (including stackoverflow.com and my wife's blog) won't load in Firefox or Chrome but will in Opera or with curl and wget.

When I'm at home using wifi, all effected sites load normally in Firefox and Chrome.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Are firefox and chrome both using adblocking extensions? If so try disabling them. Could be an arrant host setting them off.

Comment: Chrome doesn't have a blocker, and for Firefox disabling it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You're browser might be attempting to force IPv6 browsing.

You can test this hypothesis by going to `about:config` in Firefox then setting the attribute `network.dns.disableIPv6` to 'true'.